# Convert all values of Container into NSString

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

I have a problem to communicate with a server. The webserver expects all parameters in the JSON object to be a string. So every number and every boolean in every container needs to be a string.

For my example I have a `NSDictionary` full of key values (values are all kinds of types - numbers, arrays etc.). For example:

```
{
"AnExampleNumber":7e062fa,
"AnExampleBoolean":0,
"AnExampleArrayOfNumber":[17,4,8]
}
```

Has to become:

```
{
"AnExampleNumber":"7e062fa",
"AnExampleBoolean":"0",
"AnExampleArrayOfNumber":["17","4","8"]
}
```

I tried the standard `NSJSONSerializer` but it doesn't give me any option to do what I need. I then tried to transform everything in the dictionary manually to be a string but that seems to be overhead. Does anyone have hint for me? Maybe a serializer that does just that or a function to convert any objects in a container to strings?

Comment: Bad server implementation.

Comment: Definitely, I'm completely with you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(I assume you mean `NSJSONSerializer`, not `NSSerializer`.)

I doubt you'll find a pre-rolled solution to this. It's not a general problem. As you note, this is incorrect JSON, so JSON serializers shouldn't do it.

The best solution IMO is just write the code to transform your `NSDictionary` into another `NSDictionary` that is in the form you want. If you really want to make it a generic solution, I suspect that a custom `NSDictionary` walker with `isKindOfClass:` is your best bet. Something like this should work:

```
NSDictionary *myStringDictForDict(NSDictionary *dict); // forward decl if needed

NSArray *myStringArrayForArray(NSArray *array) {
    NSMutableArray *result = [NSMutableArray new];
    [array enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        if ([obj isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) {
            [result addObject:myStringArrayForArray(obj)];
        } else if ([obj isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
            [result addObject:myStringDictForDict(obj)];
        } else {
            [result addObject:[obj description]];
        }
    }];

    return result;
}

NSDictionary *myStringDictForDict(NSDictionary *dict) {
    NSMutableDictionary *result = [NSMutableDictionary new];
    [dict enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(id key, id obj, BOOL *stop) {
       if ([obj isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) {
            result[key] = myStringArrayForArray(obj);
        } else if ([obj isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
            result[key] = myStringDictForDict(obj);
        } else {
            result[key] = [obj description];
        }
    }];

    return result;
}
```

Comment: worked :) Thanks. I still will talk to the server guy ;)

Answer (score 2):

This is one way you could do it. It's non-optimized and has no error handling. It only supports the kinds of objects that NSJSONSerializer supports.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface NSObject(SPWKStringify) 
- (id)spwk_stringify;
@end

@implementation NSObject(SPWKStringify) 
- (id)spwk_stringify
{
    if ([self isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
        NSDictionary *dict = (NSDictionary *)self;
        NSMutableDictionary *newDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

        for (NSString *key in [dict allKeys]) {
            newDict[key] = [dict[key] spwk_stringify];
        }

        return newDict;
    } else if ([self isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) {
        NSMutableArray *newArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

        for (id value in ((NSArray *)self)) {
            [newArray addObject:[value spwk_stringify]];
        }

        return newArray;
    } else if (self == [NSNull null]) {
        return @"null"; // representing null as a string doesn't make much sense
    } else if ([self isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]) {
        return self;
    } else if ([self isKindOfClass:[NSNumber class]]) {
        return [((NSNumber *)self) stringValue];
    }

    return nil;
}
@end

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        NSDictionary *dict = @{
            @"AnExampleNumber": @1234567,
            @"AnExampleBoolean": @NO,
            @"AnExampleNull": [NSNull null],
            @"AnExampleArrayOfNumber": @[@17, @4, @8],
            @"AnExampleDictionary": @{@"innerKey": @[@55, @{@"anotherDict": @[@"foo", @[@1, @2, @"three"]]}]}
        };

        NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:[dict spwk_stringify] options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:NULL]; 
        NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

        NSLog(@"result: %@", jsonString);
    }
}
```

The output will be:

```
result: {
  "AnExampleNumber" : "1234567",
  "AnExampleNull" : "null",
  "AnExampleDictionary" : {
    "innerKey" : [
      "55",
      {
        "anotherDict" : [
          "foo",
          [
            "1",
            "2",
            "three"
          ]
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  "AnExampleBoolean" : "0",
  "AnExampleArrayOfNumber" : [
    "17",
    "4",
    "8"
  ]
}
```

**Note**: Please keep in mind that turning `[NSNull null]` into a string doesn't make any sense and might actually be misleading and dangerous.

Enjoy.